# Denial of a statement with existential quantifier

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

For $U$ the universe under consideration, $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ predicates with free variable $x$, I want to find a useful denial of

$$
(\exists x \in {U})(Q(x) \land P(x)).
$$

Now I'm aware of the fact that $\lnot (\exists x)(P(x)) = (\forall x)(\lnot P(x))$, but I don't know how to deal with $\lnot (\exists x\in U)$. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that $(\exists x\in U)(P(x))$ really means $(\exists x)(x\in U \land P(x))$.

Comment: "I am aware of the fact that $\neg(\exists x)(P(x)) = (\forall x)(P(x))$." You are missing a negation; it's $\neg(\exists x)(P(x)) = (\forall x)(\neg P(x))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $(\exists x\in U)$ is called a modified quantifier since it modifies the existential quantifier $(\exists x)$ and the notation
$$
(\exists x\in U)(P(x)),
$$

is actually an abbreviation for the statement

$$
(\exists x)(x\in U \land P(x)). \quad\quad (*)
$$

Similarly, $(\forall x\in U)$ is actually an abbreviation for the statement

$$
(\forall x)(x\in U \to P(x)). \quad\quad (**)
$$

With $(*)$ and (**) in mind, we have
$$
(\exists x \in {U})(Q(x) \land P(x)) = (\exists x)(x\in U \land (Q(x) \land P(x)));
$$

Its negation is

\begin{align*}
\lnot(\exists x \in {U})(Q(x) \land P(x)) & \equiv (\forall x)(\lnot(x\in U) \lor \lnot(Q(x) \land P(x)))\\
&\equiv (\forall x) (\lnot(x\in U) \lor (\lnot Q \lor \lnot P(x)))\\
&\equiv (\forall x) (x\in U \to (\lnot Q \lor \lnot P(x)))\\
&\equiv (\forall x\in U) (\lnot Q \lor \lnot P(x))\\
&\equiv (\forall x\in U) (Q \to \lnot P(x)).
\end{align*}

To arrive at the final result I have used the fact that $Q\to P\equiv \lnot Q\lor P$.

Comment: It shuld be $\rightarrow$ rather than $\Rightarrow$; the latter is semantic, and here you want the syntactic symbol.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! is that universally accepted? For instance, Lakins(2016) The Tools of Mathematical Reasoning uses the later.

Comment: If you are doing propositional calculus, then the connective symbol is $\rightarrow$. We generally use $\Rightarrow$ outside of propositional calculus. But here you are doing propositional calculus.

Comment: I typically use $\to$ to denote a mapping but you are right I guess. I'll edit my post. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Sorry for the simple question: what is the = symbol with a bar over it?

Comment: @laurab: I guess you mean $\equiv$ :-)... In latex, \equiv, it's the propositional calculus symbol for indicating "equivalent to".

Comment: Yes I mean that, thank you very much.